# Rubocop in VS Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I'm a beginner in ruby on rails. I installed it and created a project. Then opened it in VS Code. But Rubocop didn't work. When I write in terminal "rubocop", I'm getting a message: "Rubocop found unknown Ruby version: 3.2". Then I tried to upgrade it to 1.59.0, but it didn't help. He gives the same error, and just as before the update, when checking the version, he writes 0.89.1

How I can fix it????

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the gems  `'rubocop'` and `'rubocop-rails'` added to your gemfile? There is also `'rubocop-rspec'` that you can add for test files. Then you need a `.rubocop.yml` file that contains any specific rules as well as this to require it in your project:

```
require:
  - rubocop-rails
  - rubocop-rspec
```

See the configuration docs for more info.
https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to do some more different things with robocop, and suddenly everything worked!) But now for some reason I can't ask questions for 2 days... :(